# React native cloned element is losing value reference

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a component to validate a form, the plan is to have a function that checks "required" elements to add additional props to it.

What I'm currently doing is cloning the elements with the new properties like this

```
cloneChildren(children, validate) {
    const result = {
        children: [],
        errors: [],
        status: true
    };
    children.forEach(child => {
        const options = {
        };
        if (this.willValidate(child.props)) {
            options.error = null;
        }
        result.children.push(React.cloneElement(child, options));
    });
    return result;
}
```

My render looks like this:

```
render() {
    const clones = this.cloneChildren(this.props.children);
    // this.setState({
    //     children: clones.children
    // })

    const children = clones.children;
    return children;
}
```

to use it I do just pass children to it

```
<Form>
   <Input required="true" value={this.state.name} />
   <Input required="true" value={this.state.age} />
</Form>
```

This works, I'm able to put props to the object if it has a validation error or whatever.

However this came with a nasty side effect, I'm losing the value reference of the object, meaning if the object started with a value of empty or a specific value it keeps that value and it doesn't change

If I type on the object it re-renders and sets the value back to the value it had when cloned.

Is there a way on cloning to keep references to values ({this.state.value}) originally passed when creating the child?

See jsfiddle of issue

https://jsfiddle.net/josesuero/ftce52u8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You're overwriting props with options. Save the options to the props and also save the current value to oldValue right before cloning. Something like

```
React.cloneElement(child, Object.assign({}, this.props, { options: options, oldValue: this.props.value }));
```

Happy to give more help if you create a codepen/jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tried but is not working, created jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/josesuero/ab4c5z2o/